# How to get user input in Yesod without using Yesod Form

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

In my page I have a search field(text area).

Yesod Form is quite complicated to use, so I figure I'll just use Javascript to get the value typed by the user. But then how my Haskell program gets that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a HTTP request to the server and pass it data.

In case of GET request, you just declare handler parameters in `config/routes` and then get them as `getYourHandlerR` arguments. In case of POST, you can use [requireJsonBody](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.6/yesod-core-1.4.32/Yesod-Core-Json.html#v:requireJsonBody) to get data as JSON or [getPostParams](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.6/yesod-core-1.4.32/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:getPostParams).

Comment: Wow this is clever and WAY easier than using Yesod Form + bootstrap!